# Writing a master thesis in a totally new field?

Tags: thesis, university

One year ago I started an interdisciplinary master programme. It is now time to choose my master thesis topic and the one I have in mind is totally unrelated to my bachelor and quite distant from my current expertise.

I know, that if I were to choose this topic and write a good thesis I would have to acquire substantially new knowledge & skills.

Although I have 9 months to write my thesis, I am considering taking a year off to get caught up on the said topics, and then starting next year.

Is this advisable?

Would you take up the challenge to get acquainted **while** writing the thesis or only start researching **after** you've familiarised yourself with the basics?

Comment: What does your adviser says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be different from country to country, but where I did my Masters project (Denmark) your judged on what is expected to be learned (with of course a basic-level start knowledge) within the allocated time for the project. Hence, I would not advise to take a year out to get acquainted.

However, it should also be noted that in Denmark you get money to study and so a year of would mean you would need another income. Opposite to other places (like US) where it cost you money to study.